# Stopping a function and starting another

Tags: javascript, jquery, velocity.js

I'm trying to make a small animation (using [Velocity.js](http://velocityjs.org/)) that alternates between two looping states when an svg is clicked. The first state is horizontally from `scaleX(1)` to `scaleX(2.5)` back to `scaleX(1)` at `scaleY(1)`, the second is vertically `scaleY(1)` to `scaleY(8)` back to `scaleY(1)` at `scaleX(2.5)`. When the svg is clicked the animation starts in it's horizontal state, clicked again, the state that was just active (horizontal) should stop, and the alternative state should start (vertical), every click changes to the alternate state. Ideally the state change is seamless in the sense that svg should scale to the correct scale on the axis that is not animating whilst the new active state is animating.

This is a gif of what i'm trying to achieve, the blue dot symbolises a click:
[image]

My current outcome is embedded, the problem i'm having is that only one state change occurs so I need to stop the previous animation. The other problem is that in the transition, the scaling does not happen at the same time, i.e the new active state's animation does not happen at the same time as scaling of the axis that is not animating in the new state. Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

```js
// LINKs TO VELOCITY
// https://rawgit.com/julianshapiro/velocity/master/velocity.min.js
// https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.5.0/velocity.min.js

var Rightscale = {
    chooser: 0,
    svg: $('#right').find('svg'),

    init: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
        Rightscale.svg.on("click", function() {
            console.log(Rightscale.chooser)
            if(Rightscale.chooser === 0) {
                Rightscale.chooser = 1;
                Rightscale.horizontal();
            } else {
                Rightscale.chooser = 0;
                Rightscale.vertical();
            }
        })
    },
    
    horizontal: function() {
        Rightscale.svg.velocity({
            scaleX: 2.5,
            scaleY: 1
        }, {
            duration: 3000,
            loop: true, 
            easing: "linear"
        })
    },

    vertical: function() {
        Rightscale.svg.velocity({
            scaleY: 8,
            scaleX: 2.5
        }, {
            duration: 3000,
            loop: true,
            easing: "linear"
        })
    },
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  Rightscale.init();
});
```

```css
#right {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.scale {
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.5.0/velocity.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/julianshapiro/velocity/master/velocity.min.js"></script>
<div id="right">
  <div class="scale">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
       viewBox="0 0 392 132" style="enable-background:new 0 0 392 132;" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
      <path d="M76.1,26.4v100.7H44.5V26.2H20.2V3.6h80v22.8H76.1z"/>
      <path d="M113,127.1V3.6h69.5v22.6H145v27.3h32.4v22.6h-32.2v28.2h38.4v22.8H113z"/>
      <path d="M235.6,129.3c-26.7,0-40.7-11.9-40.7-34.6c0-4.5,0.2-6.6,1.1-11.5h26.4l-0.2,2.6c-0.2,2.3-0.2,4.5-0.2,6.6
        c0,10.7,4.7,16.4,13.7,16.4c8.1,0,12.8-5.1,12.8-13.7c0-7.5-3.6-13-9.8-15.6l-12.4-4.9C204.5,65.9,197,56.3,197,37.7
        C197,13.4,210.9,1,238.6,1c24.5,0,36.7,10,36.7,29.9c0,4.3-0.4,6.4-1.3,11.9h-26.5c0.6-4.5,0.8-6.2,0.8-8.8
        c0-8.5-3.6-12.8-10.2-12.8c-6.4,0-10.9,4.9-10.9,11.9c0,7.2,3.6,10.9,14.7,15.4l15.8,6.2c15.8,6.4,23.7,18.1,23.7,35.4
        C281.3,115.4,265.1,129.3,235.6,129.3z"/>
      <path d="M345.5,26.4v100.7h-31.6V26.2h-24.3V3.6h80v22.8H345.5z"/>
    </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is the desired effect you wanted. But I added a line in your click handler that stops current animations.

```js
// LINKs TO VELOCITY
// https://rawgit.com/julianshapiro/velocity/master/velocity.min.js
// https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.5.0/velocity.min.js

var Rightscale = {
    chooser: 0,
    svg: $('#right').find('svg'),

    init: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
        Rightscale.svg.on("click", function() {
            Rightscale.svg.velocity("stop", true);
            console.log(Rightscale.chooser)
            if(Rightscale.chooser === 0) {
                Rightscale.chooser = 1;
                Rightscale.horizontal();
            } else {
                Rightscale.chooser = 0;
                Rightscale.vertical();
            }
        })
    },
    
    horizontal: function() {
        Rightscale.svg.velocity({
            scaleX: 2.5,
            scaleY: 1
        }, {
            duration: 3000,
            loop: true, 
            easing: "linear"
        })
    },

    vertical: function() {
        Rightscale.svg.velocity({
            scaleY: 8,
            scaleX: 2.5
        }, {
            duration: 3000,
            loop: true,
            easing: "linear"
        })
    },
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  Rightscale.init();
});
```

```css
#right {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.scale {
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.5.0/velocity.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/julianshapiro/velocity/master/velocity.min.js"></script>
<div id="right">
  <div class="scale">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
       viewBox="0 0 392 132" style="enable-background:new 0 0 392 132;" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
      <path d="M76.1,26.4v100.7H44.5V26.2H20.2V3.6h80v22.8H76.1z"/>
      <path d="M113,127.1V3.6h69.5v22.6H145v27.3h32.4v22.6h-32.2v28.2h38.4v22.8H113z"/>
      <path d="M235.6,129.3c-26.7,0-40.7-11.9-40.7-34.6c0-4.5,0.2-6.6,1.1-11.5h26.4l-0.2,2.6c-0.2,2.3-0.2,4.5-0.2,6.6
        c0,10.7,4.7,16.4,13.7,16.4c8.1,0,12.8-5.1,12.8-13.7c0-7.5-3.6-13-9.8-15.6l-12.4-4.9C204.5,65.9,197,56.3,197,37.7
        C197,13.4,210.9,1,238.6,1c24.5,0,36.7,10,36.7,29.9c0,4.3-0.4,6.4-1.3,11.9h-26.5c0.6-4.5,0.8-6.2,0.8-8.8
        c0-8.5-3.6-12.8-10.2-12.8c-6.4,0-10.9,4.9-10.9,11.9c0,7.2,3.6,10.9,14.7,15.4l15.8,6.2c15.8,6.4,23.7,18.1,23.7,35.4
        C281.3,115.4,265.1,129.3,235.6,129.3z"/>
      <path d="M345.5,26.4v100.7h-31.6V26.2h-24.3V3.6h80v22.8H345.5z"/>
    </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @zsawaf for taking the time to reply, it's very much appreciated. I attached a gif to the original post outlining the desired effect. Your help seems to have got me closer

Comment: @CalAlt I've never used Velocity, I'd usually use CSS animations, but I'll give it a try!

Comment: @CalAlt are you open to a CSS solution? Or are you married to Velocity?